# How do i prevent the textbox cursor from blinking throu a overlayed DIV under IE8?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

this occurs only under IE8, FireFox hides the cursor as you would expect.
the DIV in question has a absolut position and z-index: 2 (increasing the z-index does not help)

just removing the focus from the textbox is not a desired solution.

Comment: uhm like the default blinking when you give the textbox a focus. it looks like this -> <blink>|</blink> :) (pretending that HTML would be allowed in comments)

Answer (score 0):

i don't think you can control that. remove the focus from that text field or change the div's background-color so the cursor isn't visible (which would be black... maybe not very beautiful...)

Answer (score 0):

I have double click on my textbox (textbox is readonly)

```
$("#myTextBox").dblclick(function () {
   ///show Overlayed div
    this.blur();
});
```

I hope it will help someone.